# Visual Studio Code incognito mode when running a web project

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am having trouble launching a web project in Google Chrome incognito mode. I have tried making changes to the launch.json file but it's not working.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        
        

        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [ "--incognito"],
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: please try with "runtimeArgs": [
                  "--remote-debugging-port=9223",
                  "--incognito"
],

Comment: I tried making these changes to "runtimeArgs" but it's still opening Google Chrome as a normal web browser.

Comment: @chubbybunny23 did you ever figure this one out? It seems like this should be a super straightforward thing, but I can't find much online about it, and the `--incognito` flag seems to have no effect.